# unable to install PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pycharm

PyTorch is working in commandline but unable to run in Pycharm IDE.Got the error on following code.
import torch
print(torch.**version**)

/Users/jamil/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /Users/jamil/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jamil/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 1, in 
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

want to use torch in pycharm

Comment: Pycharm might use its own Python version. See if you can get a terminal in Pycharm and install pytorch there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To install pytorch in pycharm go to `Python Interpreter` and use this pip command by simply typing `pip install pytorch` for more info visit [here](https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-install-pytorch-on-pycharm/)

[image: Installing pytorch]